# minimum of all rows maximum in matrix

Tags: sorting, matrix, max, rows, minimum

I have to find the minimum of every row's maximum in matrix. And then print the row which contains that element. Why it cannot be done like this ?

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]>max)
                max=a[i][j];

        }
        if(min>max){
            min=max;
            p=i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please tag the programming language you are using and provide a complete example of your problem, for example the declarations of the above variables.

Comment: I am assuming that this is C code, and my first guess would be that you compare the min with the overall max, instead of the max that just got computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `max` for each row:

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        max = 0;  // or some value less than the minimum value in the matrix

        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(a[i][j]>max)
                max=a[i][j];

        } 
        if(min>max){
            min=max;
            p=i;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, once `max` has replaced `min` once, a value can never be both greater than `max` and less than `min`.